# Bulk insert data from GridView to postgresql database in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, sqlbulkcopy

how to bulk insert large amount of data from asp.net gridview to postgresql database,i tried to use an insert statement but it takes a long time to finish.

i found an example of code to do the same task on sql server,
but with postgresql i didn't figure out how to do it.

this is the code for sql server and it works well

```
Protected Sub Bulk_Insert(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(1) {New DataColumn("CustomerId", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("CompanyName", GetType(String))})

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim CustomerId As Integer = Integer.Parse(row.Cells(1).Text)
        Dim CompanyName As String = row.Cells(2).Text
        dt.Rows.Add(CustomerId, CompanyName)
    Next
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim consString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(consString)
            Using sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "destination2"

                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerId", "CustomerId")
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CompanyName", "CompanyName")
                con.Open()
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

please any help

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Bulk Operations](https://bulk-operations.net/)

This library is not free.

Similar to `SqlBulkCopy` but for PostgreSQL, this library lets you easily to perform bulk operations such as:

- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Delete
- BulkMerge

Example:

```
var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection);
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerId", "CustomerId")
bulk.ColumnMappings.Add("CompanyName", "CompanyName")
bulk.BulkInsert(dt);
```